# ListView item layout performance

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I need the order of views which you can see at the picture. My XML layout file is below. The `TextView` with ID `eqlr_tv_question_comment` takes over all the free space and other views are not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row_9patch" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eqlr_tv_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eqlr_tv_question_comment"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_row_text_size" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eqlr_bt_create_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/eqlr_tv_question_comment"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_write_comment"
        android:contentDescription="@string/write_comment"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/twenty_dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/eqlr_tv_question_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_comment_9patch"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/comment_text_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Desired views order]

Comment: I don't know if the code is exactly as you have pasted it, but first of all, I see some typos. The edlr_tv_question_comment id should be declared as @+id/eqlr_tv_question_comment, and the layout_above attribute in the eqlr_tv_question should not have a + sign. Besides,  try removing the layout_centerVertical attributes in both of the upper TextView and ImageButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous idea was bad because

- using nested layouts leads to poor UI performance,
- `android:drawableRight` should be used  instead of an `ImageView` if 
  a little icon should be to the right of text (unless the icon is clickable)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_go"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/question"
    android:background="@drawable/comment"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="75dp"
    android:text="@string/short_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

These two commands are mutually exclusive:

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/eqlr_tv_question_comment"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Remove both of the `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` attributes.

`centerVertical` takes precedence and `above` is completely ignored. Since `eqlr_tv_question_comment` TextView is the last View added, it is probably sitting on top of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I prefferred two `LinearLayout`s to one `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row_9patch"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/fifteen_dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eqlr_tv_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/exercise_list_row_tv_weight"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_row_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eqlr_bt_create_comment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/exercise_list_row_iv_weight"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_write_comment"
            android:contentDescription="@string/write_comment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eqlr_tv_question_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_comment_9patch"
        android:text="@string/test_indicator_descr"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/comment_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using two layouts like this is bad and is advised against in the docs [http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

Comment: Link is down. New link: [Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)